# MVC site-wide logging actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging

Is there an easy way to do a site-wide logging of `Actions`? By this I mean record any execution of code in the `Controller`, along with datetime stamp and IP address.

Comment: Create a base controller class with the built-in logging functionality and derive all controllers from it?

Answer (score 2):

I found a good tutorial to add a Global Filter in the end.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters